# <ul> image is overlappingthe <li> image

Tags: html, css

I have a background image 'selector' which is used by a `<ul>`tag. I have a jquery function that calls the class Lightselector when the `<ul>` menu item is selected. The light selector class is rendered by the `<li>` tag but my problem is that the `<li>` tag background image (lightselector class) overlaps the background image of the `<ul>` image 'selector'. I've tried z-index and background position.

Html:

```
<ul>BUMPER STICKERS
    <li>hello </li>
    <li>This is a paragraph.</li>
</ul>
<ul>BUMPER STICKERS
    <li>This is a paragraph.</li>
    <li>This is a paragraph.</li>
</ul>
```

`<li>` lightselector:

```
.LightSelector {
    background-image: url(../Images/Template%20Images/Lightblue.png);
    background-position:0% 0%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

`<ul>` background image:

```
ul {
    background-image: url(../Images/Template%20Images/selector.png);
    background-position:13% 102%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("ul").click(function (evt) {      
        if (evt.target.tagName != 'UL') return;
        $("li", this).toggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: Could you add it to a JSFiddle, it'll make it easier to understand thanks

Comment: Basically the <ul> image is overlappingthe <li> image

Comment: Do you have a live example of this?

Comment: here is the fidler but will need to find appropriate images for css http://jsfiddle.net/CL7dM/15/

Comment: I see that. But what i don't see is where you add the class .lightselector to an actual li element. I think you are not overlapping anything, because the .lightselector css element doesn't even get used.

Comment: Your markup is invalid.  Only `li` tags can be direct descendants of `ul` or `ol` tags, which means you can't have text there either.  Perhaps you would be interested in *definition lists* instead?

Comment: Yes the <ul> overlaps the <li>

Comment: I have added <ul> tags the markup isnt invalid

Comment: I need the bring the `<li>` infront of the `<ul>`

Comment: This is invalid, as cimmanon said: <ul>BUMPER STICKERS <li>hello </li>

Comment: Here's a fiddle with valid HTML and images: http://jsfiddle.net/CL7dM/22 See if you can use it to more clearly state the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check this: [jsfiddle.net/Nz3Fc/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/Nz3Fc/1)

I am not sure if I understood you, but basically I am putting the `<ul>` background image on the header text to be permanently visible, and I am showing the `<li>` background image when the header is clicked showing it accordingly.

Since the header text is not part of the `<ul>` anymore you dont have to toggle a background for another as they are independent. If it helps let me know.

The code goes as follows:

**HTML:**

```
<p>BUMPER STICKERS</p>
<ul>    
    <li>This is a paragraph.</li>
    <li>This is a paragraph.</li>    
</ul>

<p>BUMPER STICKERS</p>
<ul>
    <li>This is a paragraph.</li>
    <li>This is a paragraph.</li>    
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
p {
    background-image: url(http://placehold.it/200x50);
    background-position:13% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

ul {   
    background-position:13% 102%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.LightSelector {
    background-image: url(http://placehold.it/100x400);
    background-position:0% 0%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("p").click(function () {              
        $("ul li").toggle();        
    });

     $("ul li").click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       $("ul li").addClass("LightSelector").not(this).removeClass("LightSelector");
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I just changed the image within the li tag and made it shorter so it doesnt overlap.